# How do you create an internal URL to other dynamic items in Sitefinity 10

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, sitefinity

I wanted to know how I would go about creating a link to an item in the backend.

I have a dashboard widget I have set up already, which lists all my custom dynamic module items, but I need a way to make these clickable/editable internally by a URL rather than navigating to the item manually in the backend.

It looks like this relies on iFrames and Kendo UI etc. Does anyone have advice on this?

I can't seem to find any mention of a similar process!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to create specific URL for dynamic items, but you can create JS function and call this JS function when needed:

```
function OpenForEdit(data){
    var template = '<iframe id="sfEditingWindowFrame" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameBorder="0" border="0" src=""></iframe>';
    this.kendoWindow = jQuery("<div>").append(template).kendoWindow(this.windowOptions).data("kendoWindow");
    this.contentFrame = $(this.kendoWindow.wrapper).find("#sfEditingWindowFrame");
    $(this.kendoWindow.wrapper).addClass("sfMaximizedWindowWithIframe");
    this.contentFrame.prop("src", function() {
        var src = "/Sitefinity/Dialog/ContentViewEditDialog?ControlDefinitionName="+data.ControlDefinitionName+"&ViewName="+data.ViewName+"&IsInlineEditingMode=true";
        return src;
    });
    this.kendoWindow.maximize();
    this.kendoWindow.open();
    var that = this;
    this.contentFrame.one("load", function() {
        var frameHandle = that.contentFrame.get(0).contentWindow;
        if (frameHandle) {
            var showMoreActionsWorkflowMenu = true;
            var hideLanguageList = false;
            var commandName, params, key, commandArgument, dataItem;
            var isEditMode = true;
            commandName = "edit";
            params = {
                IsEditable: true
            };
            key = {
                Id: data.ItemId 
            };
            commandArgument = {
                languageMode: "edit",
                language: data.Culture
            };
            dataItem = {
                Id: data.ItemId,
                ProviderName: data.ProviderName
            };
            if (frameHandle.createEditingWindow) {
                frameHandle.createEditingWindow(commandName, dataItem, params, key, commandArgument, function(a, b) { window.location=data.ReturnUrl}, showMoreActionsWorkflowMenu, hideLanguageList);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Inside this function you need to pass object like this:

```
var data = {
    "ItemId": "76a1e9f5-d32e-642d-aa3a-ff0000a20aad",
    "ControlDefinitionName": "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Contest.ImageBackendDefinition",
    "ViewName": "ImageBackendEditView",
    "ProviderName": "OpenAccessProvider",
    "Culture": "en",
    "ReturnUrl": "/Sitefinity/dashboard"
};
```

You just need to change data inside this object relevant to your dynamic item.

Comment: Victor! Thanks again, I was hoping you'd reply! I have no clue with Kendo UI like I said I'm new to SF, I will give this a shot tomorrow and let you know. Once I've tried it out I'll accept the  answer. Again thank you very much for the advice!

Comment: Victor, how did you find the above resource/javascript? Thank you.

Comment: I just checked inside Sitefinity's javascript how they doing that, then I removed unnecessary code, which can confuse you

Comment: I found the script in the Telerik script library, your solution worked perfect! Thank you for the help!